# Booking System Design

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to implement a Booking system that will involve the user completing a number of steps.

How would I manage user input between these steps? I don't want to be adding the information supplied on each step to a database in case that the user doesn't complete the steps.

So I need a way of persisting data entered between page redirects and then submit that data at once to the database.

I was thinking maybe a Session array? Or maybe even MySQL using prepared statements?

I'm not sure the best way of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store everything in `$_SESSION`, and insert that data into the database (or do whatever else you want with it) at the last submission stage.

Just remember to put `session_start()` at the top of each page, or you'll get a load of `Undefined` errors.

Of course, you could use a database, but it's extra hassle - store temporary data temporarily, and then make it persistent with a database.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions makes sense. Alternatively you could add a column to db called completed, then add data on each page, then mark complete at end.

I'd use Sessions though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the people above me that sessions make sense.  Here's another option..

You could make each next button a form submit and pass a bunch of invisible fields in post to the next page you want to look at and pass the data around that way.

Answer (score 0):

Using a database is also an alternative. In case a user logs out and logs back you can assist him/her to continue the booking process s/he started.

You can save something like `current_step` in the database and purge an existing information if user wants to restart the process.

But if you are only interested in having the user complete the process in one session use `$_SESSION` to store your data.